# Postgres: invalid type name "query%ROWTYPE"

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, rowtype

I want to create a variable based on the table "query" (`l_query query%ROWTYPE`), but I got this message: `invalid type name "query%ROWTYPE"`
I also tried to use the fully qualified table name `l_query dbname.public.query%ROWTYPE`, but it didn't help me ether.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION somefunc()
RETURNS int AS $$
DECLARE
  l_res dbname.public.query%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    return 1;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

PS:I do have the table query. I checked it a couple of times. I have this error only on the production server. Locally, I ran it with no problems

```
                                       version
```

---

PostgreSQL 9.2.4 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2, 64-bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A non-quoted reference to `query` probably confuses the plpgsql parser since `QUERY` is also a keyword used in the `RETURN QUERY ...` construct.

The generic solution is to add double quotes around the problematic identifier:

```
DECLARE l_res "query"%ROWTYPE;
```

As for your fully qualified variant, there's another problem with it: only a schema name may prefix a table name, not a database name plus schema name.

These declarations should also work:

```
DECLARE l_res public."query"%ROWTYPE;
```

or

```
DECLARE l_res "public"."query"%ROWTYPE;
```

Comment: Thank you, it helped me. I knew that it could be a keyword, but I did not know about a quotation mark to get rid of ambiguous