# Postgres: invalid type name colname%TYPE

Tags: postgresql, function, psql, postgresql-9.4

I am trying to create a function in postgres 9.4 using psql as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function_name()
    RETURNS VOID AS $$
DECLARE
            et_ag "table_name"."ismask"%TYPE;
BEGIN

    SET SEARCH_PATH = overlay;


            SELECT ismask INTO et_ag FROM OVERLAY.table_name WHERE component_name = 'et_ag';

    SELECT case when et_ag != 0 then 'et_ag is not 0'  else 'et_ag is 0' end;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

On running this procedure, I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR:  invalid type name ""table_name"."ismask"%TYPE"
LINE 10:             et_ag "table_name"."ismask"%TYPE;
                       ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: invalid type name ""table_name"."ismask"%TYPE"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 167
```

I referred this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24246269/postgres-invalid-type-name-queryrowtype), but am not able to resolve the error. I will greatly appreciate and let me know what wrong I am doing while creating this function.

Comment: Error indicates that there is no such table or table dos not contains such column. Try to fully qualify it: `et_ag overlay.table_name.ismask%TYPE;`

Comment: @Abelisto Thank you for pointing that out. I can successfully create the function now!

Comment: Nice to see it. Congrats! *~<:o)